# sending value from view to controller

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a dropdown list to display values for certain building: i am not sure how can I send the value to a new page to display the values for that selected building only. i am getting the error when trying to load the page with the dropdown menu. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

here is my index.blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('custom'),$datacenter }}">
<div class="form-group" id="dropdown">
    <label>Data Center:</label>
    <select name="datacenter" id="datacenter" class="form-group">
      <option value="RDC46">RDC46</option>
      <option value="RDC03">RDC03</option>
      <option value="RDC05">RDC05</option>
      <option value="DDC21">DDC21</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
</div>
```

here is my web route:

```
Route::get('custom\{datacenter}', 'AssigneeController@custom')->name('custom');
```

and here is my controller:

```
public function custom($datacenter)
 {
     $assignees = assignee::findorfail('datacenter')->paginate(10);

     return view('custom',compact('assignees'))
         ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
 }
```

I am getting the following error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: custom] [URI:
>   custom{datacenter}]. (View:
>   /Users/Documents/Laravel/blog/resources/views/assignees/index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like a simple `GET` request to me.

Change your form to the following:

```
<form action="{{ route('custom') }}">
    <div class="form-group" id="dropdown">
        <label>Data Center:</label>
        <select name="datacenter" id="datacenter" class="form-group">
            <option value="RDC46">RDC46</option>
            <option value="RDC03">RDC03</option>
            <option value="RDC05">RDC05</option>
            <option value="DDC21">DDC21</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In your controller:

```
public function custom(Request $request)
{
    // You will have access to the datacenter using $request->datacenter
    $assignees = assignee::findorfail($request->datacenter)->paginate(10);

    return view('custom',compact('assignees'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

There's no need for the datacenter segment in your route:

```
Route::get('custom', 'AssigneeController@custom')->name('custom');
```

Comment: yes,
 it is very simple request to show entries for specific data centre instead of all the other data centres.
I just tried your solution, I got the following error:
too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\assigneeController::custom(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Comment: @Abdul Forgot to typehint Request. Try now :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
<form action="{{ route('custom',[$datacenter]) }}">
    <div class="form-group" id="dropdown">
        <label>Data Center:</label>
        <select name="datacenter" id="datacenter" class="form-group">
          <option value="RDC46">RDC46</option>
          <option value="RDC03">RDC03</option>
          <option value="RDC05">RDC05</option>
          <option value="DDC21">DDC21</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>

    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
<form action="{{ route('custom', $datacenter)}}">
    <div class="form-group" id="dropdown">
        <label>Data Center:</label>
        <select name="datacenter" id="datacenter" class="form-group">
          <option value="RDC46">RDC46</option>
          <option value="RDC03">RDC03</option>
          <option value="RDC05">RDC05</option>
          <option value="DDC21">DDC21</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>

    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: i am getting a different error now, which says "unidentified variable :datacenter"

Comment: Did you pass the $datacenter variable ?

Comment: I have it declared in my route as follows:
Route::get('custom/{datacenter}', 'AssigneeController@custom')->name('custom');
 and in my controller:
     public function custom($datacenter)